# Visibility.GONE in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager

I am using a gridlayout with several buttons placed in a panel and I need a button placed in the middle to disappear. However, when I set the setVisible method to false, there is a space in between the buttons and I need the remaining buttons below to move up to cover the space done by the method. This is similar to the visibility mode GONE in android. How do I do this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) layout manager supports a [`hidemode`](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html) directive that does exactly this.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, is there a way to do it without using miglayout?

Comment: @louieansonng I don't know of any other layout manager that supports this out of the box. Most of them want hidden components to still take part in the layout algorithm.